# deepchem installation on mac

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, rdkit

I installed deepchem following the instruction on their [website](https://github.com/deepchem/deepchem#using-a-conda-environment).  I dint get any error during the installation but when I import deepchem from jupyternotebbok, the kernel will be dead:

```
The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.
```

If I import deepchem from terminal, I get

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the very slow answer on here! DeepChem's latest versions should work on Mac. Can you try installing DeepChem 2.3 and seeing if you're still having issues?